# Fitting a Layout inside a Cardview

Tags: java, android, android-cardview

I have a cardview with radius 10dp

I simply don't want to show the edges of layout.

I'm trying to do this > [image: click to see]

I tried `card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"` , didn't work............................................................

But I got this; [image: click to see]

**XML Code:** (I fixed, here is the code)

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:padding="6dp"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view_inner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/green"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="3dp">

    <RelativeLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
            card_view:riv_corner_radius="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/picture"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:background="@color/orange"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="text"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Share your xml code

Comment: @RedM I edited !